# Multiple questions about the same problem unanswered

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

While I was viewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299564/execution-timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the) today I noticed from the side bar at the right-linked questions that it is a duplicated and marked it with it, but I noticed a lot of question unanswered which should be deleted per my understanding as they are neither adding anything to the site nor helping the visitors searching for same problem.

I have voted to close all of those with the possible duplicate option, but what else can be done so that they can get deleted to make Stack Overflow clean?

Comment: Duplicates should not be deleted, they serve as an additional search target for the same problem.

Comment: agreed, but what if title for all is almost same?

Comment: @Stijn if the duplicate doesn't offer any new keywords, why can't we not?

Comment: In this case the duplicates with no answer don't actually offer anything useful bar the link however the titles are exact and I agree they just look like clutter.

Comment: yeah, so what is the best to do, flag it, if yes with what ?

Comment: @Braiam That wasn't clear from the question, and I didn't really pay attention to the content of the side bar when looking at the linked SO question.

Comment: Ideally one would find an answered dupe and close all dupes against it

Comment: I see quite a number of "unanswered" questions that, in fact, have answers in the comments. I think it would be better not to delete unless there were neither answers nor comments.

Comment: Is there a way to combine questions into one to keep this site clean? The side effect of many unanswered question is the frustration the user gets when trying to find one that has been properly answered - especially when doing Google searches.

Comment: @OverlordvI: Close voters can mark as duplicate; moderators can merge if the answers are directly applicable with almost no changes necessary, even superficial.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad You close it first, downvote if necessary, then cast a delete vote if you can, if you can't you move on.

Comment: What's unclear about this? It baffles me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what else can be done so that they can get deleted to make Stack Overflow clean?

Well, you can use the features of [roomba](/questions/tagged/roomba) to do such, as a single downvote will clear them up. Other than that, you can use delete votes. Apart of those two, there isn't much you can do.